# Java Disabled JLabel Reports Mouse Clicked

Tags: java, swing, mouse, click

```
colLabels[i].addMouseListener(new MyAdapter());
```

---

```
private class MyAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

     ColJLabel colJLabel = (ColJLabel)event.getComponent();

     System.out.println(colJLabel.ColID);

     setColumnHeader(false);
    }
}
```

---

```
colLabels[i].setEnabled(flag);
```

The situation is this: Mouse clicks are trapped correctly but when i have the JLabel (ColJLabel) control disabled it still reports mouse clicks.

How can I make so that mouse clicks are only reported when the control is enabled?

Thanks.

EDIT: SOLVED

```
colJLabel.isEnabled()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution would be to check to see if the component is enabled (or better, some kind of model) within the mouse listener.